# Rails booleans - True and False vs 1 and 0

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, boolean

I recently added a new 'submitted' attribute to a Comment model in a project I'm working on. In the migration, I created the column like this: `add_column :comments, :submitted, :boolean`. **Note:** I'm using MySQL for the database.

I wanted this attribute to have a default value of `false`, so I added a `before_create` method as such:

```
before_create :default_values

def default_values
  self.submitted = false
end
```

This seemed correct to me, but whenever I would try and add a new comment, nothing would happen and the console would show errors. My create method is done via AJAX, and the controller correctly processed the method by JS, but for some reason it was defaulting to the `format html` and trying to redirect to a different page.

After a bit of playing around, I changed my `default_values` method to look like this:

```
def default_values
  self.submitted = 0
end
```

Everything worked fine after that. Does this have something to do with Rails using `tinyint` for a boolean field in the database? I would have thought it would be smart enough to make the conversion between false/true and 1/0.

Interesting to note, I tried to create a new comment through the console and was able to set my `submitted` attribute to `false` with no issues. Is there a reason why I have to use an integer instead of a true/false value?

Comment: What was the error from the console?  You can added the default on the field in the migration (below).  Note that the way you are coding it, if the object is created with submitted set to true or false, you are changing it to false when creating.  I need to see the error to know why "= false" didn't work, because it think it should have.

Comment: Marlin, I'm not too concerned about the case you brought up because when an instance of this model is created, `submitted` should always be set to false by default. Doing it initially in the migration would have been a good idea, but I'm curious as to why Rails won't let me use `false`. The error I received looked to be as if the controller skipped the `format.js` render and went straight to the HTML, which accidentally leads to a 404.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add default value to your migration:

```
add_column :comments, :submitted, :boolean, :default => false
```

Comment: That certainly would have worked, but I guess I was more interested in why exactly Rails isn't allowing me to use `false` in my `before_create` method.

Comment: I'm going to accept this as the answer, because this is probably what I should have done in the first place.

Answer (score 4):

It is smart about booleans, just use:

```
object.submitted?
```

as the access method...